# How to use grep with -f flag

Tags: grep

I want to user grep with `-f` flag.

I run like this:

```
grep -f my_file.txt *
```

`my_file.txt` has a few records that exist in some of `*` hence I expected to see it.

In my case ... it behaviors weird. I.e. it finds only the last record from `my_file.txt`.

In case I remove the last record from `my_file.txt` it finds again only the last available.

I know that all records from `my_file.txt` have a match in `*` but it finds only the last one.

I was looking for special characters, new line and etc. but did not find anything.
Any clue?

BTW, f I have only 1 record in `my_file.txt` it would find it but if I have 2 records .. it would find only the last one.

Comment: What is your goal? According to [the grep man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), `-f` works as follows: “Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.” So in your example, grep is looking for patterns in `my_file.txt`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The command finds all lines of `my_file.txt` at least in `my_file.txt` which appears from the expansion of `*`. Is your `grep` an alias or a shell function? "I was looking for special characters, new line and etc." – How exactly? Can you create a [minimal complete example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) we could use to verify?

Comment: That’s correct. In my case it finds only one last pattern from the file while file has all of patterns. In case I replace those pattern in a file it again finds only the last one. FYI: I am using a shell from MobaXterm terminal. I will try to create an example for demo. Btw … in case I use flag -E and list all patterns from my_file.txt … it finds all patterns. That’s why I assume something wrong with my my_file.txt

Comment: Make sure your file doesn't contain control characters (like ^M) that would prevent matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -nof <(cat my_file.txt | tr -d '\r') *
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This was my issue. I noticed that another option is to run dos2unix against my_file.txt and it also should fix the issue